# Изображения одинаковой высоты с flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть страница (каталог книг), где сами книги надо расположить в ряд внутри flexbox контейнера. Каждая книга находится в собственном блоке, в котором есть элемент-заголовок (название) и элемент-изображение (обложка). Нужно чтобы изображения были одинаковой высоты и в идеале заполняли весь родительский блок за вычетом заголовка. Вот на что оно похоже сейчас:

[image: Book Catalogue]

Увы, поиск по ресурсу, включая [англоязычный Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932663/flexbox-equal-height-image-columns), не привел к работающим решениям для моего случая. Мой основной вопрос, почему у изображений разная высота, несмотря на прописывание `height: 100%` элементу `img`? Как бы это разрешить?

Для полноценного кода можно посмотреть этот [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/AegisX303/o2cuwj7n/14/)

HTML:

```
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="item">
      <h2 class="catalogue">
        <a href="items/pyramid_texts.html" target="_blank">
           Тексты пирамид
        </a>
      </h2>
      <img class="catalogue"
           src="images/pyramid_texts.png" alt="Тексты пирамид">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h2 class="catalogue">
        <a href="items/coffin_texts.html" target="_blank">
           Тексты саркофагов
        </a>
      </h2>
      <img class="catalogue"
           src="images/coffin_texts.jpg" alt="Тексты саркофагов">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h2 class="catalogue">
        <a href="items/book_of_the_dead.html" target="_blank">
           Египетская книга мертвых
        </a>
      </h2>
      <img class="catalogue"
           src="images/book_of_the_dead.png" alt="Книга мертвых">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  a
  {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  a:hover
  {
    color: red;
  }

  div.flexbox
  {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  div.item
  {
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
  }

  h2
  {
    background-color: #FFF3D9;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400px;
    style: block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  img
  {
    height: 20%;
    outline: 2px solid red;
    width: 20%;
  }

  img.catalogue
  {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Укажите для изображения посередине `max-height:;`
Поставьте его основное и в консоли разработчика помаленьку уменьшайте, пока он не станет одинаковой высоты.
Перед этим убедитесь, что ширина не ограничена, поможет `width:auto;`

Comment: Выставление width: auto для этого класса изображений расширяет их до их натуральных размеров, далеко за рамками контейнеров. Я правильно понял, что вы говорите только о центральном изображении?

Comment: @AegisX303 У Вас одна из картинок слетела, пожалуйста, поправьте